# How to set recurrence to run every 15 mins in logic apps from 6 am to 7 pm in azure

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, recurrence

i have a logic app set up to run  but the last 15 minutes does not run if  i set an additional hour it runs 3 additional times for example i want a recurrence trigger set to run from 6 am to 7 pm each 15 minutes, so i chose the below:

[image: image for reference]

now if you look close the last run time is 18:45 that translates to 6:45 pm how can i get it to finish at 19:00, if i choose 19:00 for the hour it runs it until 19:45 pm

Comment: Just add 19? I.e. 7pm

Comment: @Skin if i add 19 it runs till 19:45 i want the job to end at 7 pm not 7.45 pm.

Comment: Ooooo, good point. Tricky one. Maybe you can add another trigger and do it that way by adding the one gap of 7pm.

Comment: You could also add a trigger condition … IF, it’s supported by recurrence.

Comment: I thought historically you could add more than one trigger, if that was the case, it's not anymore.  Another approach you could take is to create two logic apps that call the one that has all of the business logic.  For of the calling apps, set it up the same as what you have an for the other, it can be setup to only run at 7pm every day, that closes the gap.

Answer (score 0):

***You can select integer values from 0 to 59 i.e 0 minutes to 59 minutes:***

[image]

***This might be the limitation, so you can only get 18:45 :***

[image]

For further you can follow this [tutorial](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/logic-apps/tutorial-build-schedule-recurring-logic-app-workflow.md) for clear understanding.